# Storing multiple values in datatable dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, web-controls

I have a textbox and button. On button click, the data entered in the textbox is stored in the datatable, and this datatable bound to a gridview. Whenever I enter new data and click the button, the previously entered data is not displayed in the gridview.

How can I keep the data in the datatable on every button click?

Comment: No code generally means no answer...

Comment: @user174 Please understand that we need to see your code to help you.Keep that in mind while asking questions.

Answer (score 1):

Just call `gridView.DataBind()` to refresh the data. If your add is causing a postback then you need to make sure you do it after the page has loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Call the method to get data in gridview again.

```
protected void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = data;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
```